# Play YouTube video in app

Tags: android, ios, youtube, appcelerator

I am developing an app for a client to get all the videos from a YouTube channel and I paint all of these videos into a table, showing the thumbnail and the description, so that when the user tap the row, the video will be played.

I am using the Titanium.Platform.openURL(...) but the client wants
the video to open inside the app like Twitter and other apps.

Is there any module to do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

iPhone | Android
Titanium Appcelerator SDK: 7.1.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098147/play-youtube-video-in-app-in-android

Comment: Thanks @Cœur but the link you send me is for native android development, i am using Titanium Appcelerator.

Comment: Come on!  .... may I know the reason for down votes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the examples in this post: [Embeded Youtube video to WebView (Appcelerator) doesn't show (black screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904600/embeded-youtube-video-to-webview-appcelerator-doesnt-show-black-screen)

They use a webview solution. But you can also try to use Hyperloop and implement e.g. https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for iOS you can play in WebView and for Android there is a immersive module present.